# How to create human-readable URLs in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a simple app blog.
`Django==2.0.4`
I want to create human-readable URLs.
`models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)
```

To this model, I will add `slug = models.SlugField('id_url', max_length=255, unique=True)` , right?
Next, I will add to urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path(r'post/<str:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

Right?
But I do not understand what I need to add to `views.py` and need or not me `def get_absolute_url(self)` in `models.py`, I hope you help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your model you would want

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/post/%s' % (self.slug)
```

or

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return redirect('post_detail', slug=self.slug)
```

Within your views you would write as normal:

```
def post_detail(request):
    #do something
    return render(request, 'post-detail.html', context)
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vr8RSwXW - it is not working and why I do not understand.
https://pastebin.com/qJ5BvGUD - it is my urls and  https://pastebin.com/9q80gtQE my models.py.

Comment: what's your html?

Comment: Your model doesn't have a field called `slug`